# MySql with XPath versus MySql in unison with MongoDB for unusual structure requirements

Tags: mysql, xml, mongodb, database-design, nosql

If your database needs to contain [complex relationships/constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618696/database-design-normalization-structure-needs-to-contain-ands-ors-optional-e) would you rather:

- `Option 1`: a simple MySql structure with an XML field in one table, which you'd query using XPath ([ExtractValue()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue)).
- `Option 2`: the same simple MySql structure plus a separate MongoDB setup containing the MongoDB equivalent of the XML`*`,

And **why?**

---

**Assumptions:**

- If a whole entity needed to be deleted it would be easier with option 1 (just delete the whole tuple).
- The MongoDB query would be quicker than XPath. But this needs to be done after the MySql query, unless the ID was retrieved in an earlier query.
- Minor updates would be quicker/easier with option 2, because with MySql's XML function [UpdateXML()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_updatexml) you can only update the *whole* of the XML.
- Have to be more careful with Option 2; when inserting/updating, I'll have to make sure not to insert/update the MongoDB if the MySql insert/update query failed.
- Ignoring the 'simple MySql structure' part (joins, etc.), there's only so much I can do with [ExtractValue()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) (Option 1); I'd need to retrieve a large chunk of the XML and do the rest in my PHP/JS. Whereas MongoDB can handle a lot more.

---

**Notes:**

> - `*` plus the ID corresponding to the MySql tuple which it belongs.
> - Correct me if I am wrong about any of my assumptions.

---

#### Edit:

Either way, it'll be PHP or JS via PHP I'll be using to interact with the database(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely store the structure in MongoDB. Typically, BSON is a lot easier/cleaner than using XML to represent complex relationships (and you can also read/edit it cleanly from the shell). There are a lot of atomic operations in MongoDb which make modifications fast and easy.

Take a look at these operations for in-place document updates:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

You can also pull individual fields/sections of the document:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries

For concurrency purposes, you can also use findAndModify if you have multiple applications/threads making changes concurrently.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command